# Confused on rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having this really confusing rails error. If anyone can explain what this means than that will be helpful

Subscription#unseen_count delegated to notification_count.unseen_count, but notification_count is nil: #

Here is the subscription model

```
    class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :notification_count, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :subscribe_id, :presence => true
  after_create :notification_unseen_count
  delegate :unseen_count, to: :notification_count, allow_nil: true

  # Add the new subscription of the user with the provider
  def self.add_subscription(user, subscribe)
    user.subscriptions.where(:subscribe_id => subscribe.id).first_or_create
  end

  # Remove the subscription of the user with the provider
  def self.remove_subscription(user, subscribe)
    user.subscriptions.where(:subscribe_id => subscribe.id).destroy_all
  end

  # Get the provider with the subscription
  def subscribe
    User.find(subscribe_id)
  end

  # Mark as read the notification count as soon as the users goes to providers feed
  def mark_as_read
    notification_count.update(:unseen_count => 0)
  end

  private

  # As soon as the new subscription will create the notification count will be added fot the subscriber
  def notification_unseen_count
    NotificationCount.create(:subscription_id => self.id)
  end   
end
```

And here is the notification model:

```
class NotificationCount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :premium_subscription
  validates :subscription_id, :presence => true
  validates :premium_subscription_id, :presence => true

  # Update the notification count when the new content lived for all the subscribed users
  def self.update_notification_count subscriptions
    subscriptions.each{ |subscription| subscription.notification_count.update(:unseen_count => subscription.unseen_count + 1)}

end
```

Edit: A few hours later and no avail. If anybody has any incites on this problem than please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delegate` lets you make a contained object's method available as if it were a method on the object itself.

So in this case instead of writing `subscription.notification_count.unseen_count` you can use `subscription.unseen_count` and Rails will automatically call through to the `unseen_count` method on the associated `notification_count` for you.

However if a subscription doesn't have an associated `notification_count` you'll encounter the error you're seeing.

In your code `after_create :notification_unseen_count` is intended to create a `NotificationCount` for each `Subscription` when the `Subscription` is created so it looks like you may just have some invalid data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `allow_nil: true` on your delegation to prevent this error.
It happens because you delegated `unseen_count` on your `Subscription` model but it is `nil`

[Docs for delegate method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

Comment: Is there a way to make it not nil... sorry... I'm still learning on how all this works. Thank you so much for your help : )

Comment: You would need to show the code for both models in order for me to help further

Comment: I added the models. Thank you again for the help : )

Comment: Do you have any updates on what you think the error is?

Comment: @Jakxna360 I had posted an answer with some details, but at the time you'd accepted Carl's answer so I thought you were all sorted and had deleted my post. I've undeleted it now in case it helps.